# BigQuery: Query is not working on the Polygon Public dataset, but works with the Etherium dataset. Gives 'This query will process 0 B when run.'

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to get the data of the transactions happened in the last 5 minutes on the Polygon network. I am writing a query inBigQuery using the Polygon public dataset. But it says This query will process 0 B when run. But the same query work s with the Etherium dataset.

```
SELECT tr.from_address, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS now
FROM \`bigquery-public-data.crypto_polygon.transactions\` as tr
WHERE tr.value > 0 AND tr.block_timestamp > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) LIMIT 10
```

This is the query to get the transactions from the last 5 minutes. This query works with the Etherium's transaction table.

```
SELECT tr.from_address, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS now
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.transactions` as tr
WHERE tr.value > 0 AND tr.block_timestamp > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) LIMIT 10
```

Update - Data is not available after the 7th Sept 2022

Answer (score 0):

After analysing the dataset `crypto_polygon` and `crypto_ethereum`, I can see that both queries are working as intended.

When querying the `crypto_polygon.transactions` table,

```
WHERE tr.value > 0 AND tr.block_timestamp > TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

condition will prove to be false since the table is updated till **2022-09-06 06:37:16 UTC**
hence, you're getting the message '*This query will process 0 B when run'* as the query doesn't have the data to scan.

However, In case of `crypto_ethereum.transaction` table, block_timestamp column is updated till the current date.

Comment: Is the crypto_polygon.transactions table not updated in real time or has it stopped updating?

Comment: It looks like It has stopped updating, if you intend to use it I would advise you to create public issue tracker [thread](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to know the precise reason behind it.